# Hardware requirments for mitmproxy

Tags: ubuntu-13.10, mitmproxy

I am trying to implement mitmproxy on my own PC. Do I need 2 lan cards for this.

I cannot understand how to change the gateway of my computer to the mitmproxy server address.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. It is a proxy and it works like a proxy:

1) your browser or whatever you use tries to open something via this proxy,

2) this proxy does something on request and sends this request further, to the upstream proxy or to the target host,

3) the proxy then gets the response and does something to it,

4) the proxy returns it back to your browser or scraper

The key is the port number on which the proxy is.

Answer (score 1):

Just start the mitmproxy on default port.
using command:

```
mitmproxy -T --host
```

this will start a blue screen terminal on which bottom right you will see the port number on which that mitm is working so just forward your browser port or any device port on which you want debug.